# How can I make a Java Spring Component class thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest

I have a spring class that when you call `httpDatastoreFacade.getDatastore()` it should give you the REST request thread safe datastore:

```
@Component
public class HttpDatastoreFacade {
  private Boolean useAttribute = Boolean.FALSE;

  public String getDatastore() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextholder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    String datastore = request.getParameter("datastore");

    if(useAttribute) {
      datastore = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("datastore"));
    }

    return datastore;
  }

  public void setDatastore(String datastore, Boolean useAttribute) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextholder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    request.setAttribute("datastore", datastore);
    this.useAttribute = useAttribute;
  }

  public Boolean getUseAttribute() {
    return useAttribute;
  }
}
```

Sometimes in my code I need to change that `datastore` but then I want to immediately change it back after I call whatever code needs the `datastore` differently:

```
 @Component
  public class someClass() {
    @Autowired
    private HttpDatastoreFacade datastoreFacade;

   @Autowired
   private OtherClass otherClass;

   public void someMethod() {
     String savedDatastore = datastoreFacade.getDatastore();
     String savedUseAttribute = datastoreFacade.getUseAttribute;

     //setDatastore to new settings 
     datastoreFacade.setDatastore("newStore", true);

     //this is where I call my method's or methods that need this new datastore
     otherClass.callSomeMethod();

     //set the datastore back to old value
     datastoreFacade.setDatastore(savedDatastore , savedUseAttribute );
   }
 }
```

My issue is that I'm running into threading problems where `useAttribute` is true but the `datastore` isn't set in the request attribute.

I'm looking for a better java pattern where I can lock the `HttpDatastoreFacade` while I do my `otherClass.callSomeMethod()` or whatever other calls I need to make until I set the `HttpDatastoreFacade` back to normal.  `otherCalss.callSomeMethod` may be calling other methods that use `HttpDatastoreFacade` as well and they may want to set it how they need it.  So maybe I need some short of `datastore` stack that is thread safe?

Comment: What you are doing does not make sense. Why dont you simply pass your datastore name as an argument to callSomeMethod()?

Comment: Because callSomeMethod doesn't directly use httpDatastoreFacade.  It could be 50 calls down that httpDatastoreFacade is injected and used.  So I don't want to have to pass the facade to each method down the stack.

Comment: Wow, your call stack is 50 levels deep. Anyway, Spring framework is not meant to do things this way, you probably should change your design.

Comment: Besides passing the datastoreFacade around.  What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bean in `@RequestScope` could solve your problem.

```java
@Component
@RequestScope
public class X {
    //
}
```

you won't have to think about clearing the request scoped bean as you would the ThreadLocal. It will be collected when the corresponding ServletRequest is cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making `useAttribute` a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable which solved my problems.

```
private ThreadLocal<Boolean> useAttribute = new ThreadLocal<>();
```